# How to remove duplicate item in List?

Tags: python

If I have a list for example :

```
courses = [{name: a, course: math, count:1}]
```

and if I input again name: a course: math the list will be

```
  courses = {name: a, course: math, count:2}
```

I just want the item with the same name and course will not append to the list but only increasing 'count' key item.

I tried :

```
def add_class(inputname,inputcourse):
for i in (len(courses)):
      if courses[i]['name']== inputname and courses[i]['course']==inputcourse:
          courses[i][count]+=1
      else :
          newdata = {"name":inputname, "course":inputcourse,count:1}
          #i put count because this item is the first time.
          courses.append(newdata)
      print courses
```

I expect the output is class = `{name: a, course: math, count:2}` but the actual output is class = `[{name: a, course: math, count:2},{name: a, course: math, count:1}]`
if i input a new data like name : a, course: physic the output will be
`[{name:a,course:physic,count:1},{name: a, course: math, count:2},{name: a, course: math, count:1}]`

Comment: Python version? I know it is not the case just out of curiosity

Comment: Is `class` a list? I thought because of the `append` keyword.

Comment: That's not valid JSON...

Comment: @kvk30 it is 2.7

Comment: I am a newbie of Python and i follow the example that to make a CRUD in json, and i thought to add an item in json is .append @BlueSheepToken

Comment: In python, you only have dict, not json :), furthermore, can you provide an example when you add another course (not a math course)?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken um really? but can you please suggest me to solve my problem like i dont have to use json but how can i increase the count without adding a new item in the list. Yes i have edited my question

Comment: This isn't meaningfully "in JSON" at all. These are standard Python data structures. Something is only JSON while it's serialized to be a JavaScript Object Notation-format string -- as soon as you parse it into a Python-native structure, it isn't JSON anymore; and when you define something in native Python syntax, it was never JSON in the first place.

Comment: BTW, `class` is a Python keyword -- I'm actually surprised that the parser lets you shadow it (by using it for a variable name) at all. `course`, as suggested by BlueSheepToken in their answer, is certainly much preferable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes so is it a list or dictionary? i want to edit my question title * sorry im a newbie

Comment: `{'name': 'a', 'course': 'math'}`, when parsed by a Python interpreter, is a dictionary. Whereas `[{'name': 'a', 'course': 'math'}]` is a list which contains a dictionary.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes i know class is python keyword, i just made an example for that name , i have edited it

Comment: @Tiffany If I understand well, your output matches the putput I suggest in my answer

Comment: @BlueSheepToken yes but the other thing to check is the name too. i guess on your answer its only check the duplicate of courses of a. when i add name:b, courses : math the output should be `[{name:b,courses:math},{name:a,course:physic,count:1},{name: a, course: math, count:2},{name: a, course: math, count:1}]`

Comment: Note in [mcve] guidelines that we ask that code given in questions only have the specific bug you're asking about, but that it otherwise be complete/correct enough someone can run it to see that same bug (thus *verifying* the issue, and being able to test proposed answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for else clause. The else part will be called only if break is not reached, here is an example for you

```
courses = []
courses.append({'name': 'a', 'course': 'math', 'count': 1})
def add_course(d):
    for course in courses:
        if course['course'] == d['course'] and course['name'] == d['name']:
            course['count'] += 1
            break
    else:
        d['count'] = 1
        courses.append(d)


add_course({'name': 'a', 'course': 'math'})
add_course({'name': 'a', 'course': 'english'})
print(courses)
```

As an output you have `[{'name': 'a', 'course': 'math', 'count': 2}, {'name': 'a', 'course': 'english', 'count': 1}]`

Comment: Your output is wrong, There you will get count as the first key.

Comment: I am not sure to understand why my output is wrong, count is not a key of the dictionnary?

Comment: your output will be :
[{'count': 2, 'name': 'a', 'course': 'math'}, {'count': 1, 'name': 'a', 'course': 'english'}]

Comment: See the difference in schema when in question output you need to get count as the third key to the dictionary but in your output, it is the first key, right?

Comment: Locally, I see it as the third key, however, I am doing some searches about dict, I am quite sure the keys order is not deterministic (which might explain the difference between your computation and mine)

Comment: However, you cannot choose the order of the keys in the dict, I might not be able to do a better answer :/

Comment: @kvk30 python dictionaries are unordered, so position of key shouldnt be an issue, plus you tend to access dicts by key, so again position of key shouldnt be an issue

Comment: @BlueSheepToken i have tried your code. Thank you so much. it works :) Happy new years eve btw

Comment: @BlueSheepToken can you help me on my question that similar with this case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989370/how-to-count-arp-reply-packet-per-minute

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you a different approach?

Instead of using a list of dictionaries wich may be complicated to manage in your case, write your own class to store "name" and "course".

```
class NC:
    def __init__(self, n, c):
        self.name = n
        self.course = c

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.name, self.course))

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.__hash__() == other.__hash__():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return "[{}: {}]".format(self.name, self.course)
```

By defining the special method `__hash__` and `__eq__` you make your objects hashable, so they can be counted by [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.CounterCounter).
If you write something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

a = NC("a", "math")
b = NC("b", "physics")
c = NC("a", "math")

l = [a, b, c]

lc = Counter(l)
print lc
```

the `print` will gives you `Counter({[a: math]: 2, [b: physics]: 1})`

With this approach, you may just append all the `NC` objects to your list and at the end use Counter to get the repetitions.

**EDIT after request in the comment.**

To do the same thing in "real time" you can create an empty counter an then update it.

```
from collections import Counter

lc = Counter()

lc.update([NC("a", "math")])
print lc #this prints: Counter({[a: math]: 1})

lc.update([NC("b", "physics")])
print lc #this prints: Counter({[a: math]: 1, [b: physics]: 1})

lc.update([NC("a", "math")])
print lc #this prints: Counter({[a: math]: 2, [b: physics]: 1})
```

Just remember that `Counter.update` wants an iterable, so if you want to add one element to the Counter, you have to give in input a list with that one element. Of course you may also add more elements togheter, for example: `lc.update([NC("b", "physics"), NC("c", "chemistry")])` is valid and both objects are added to the counter.

Comment: but if i want to use it real time , is it possible? for example if i input name and course the counter will give the result after inputting the item? sorry im have not studied OOP on Python yet.

Comment: it can be done with some edits, using the methods of counter to edit the counter itself. I will edit my answer to show this.

Comment: @Tiffany here it is. Were you looking for something like that?