# How to count ARP reply packet per minute?

Tags: python, scapy

i'm setting up a local topology using GNS3. So there im using HUB, so the scenario is. There is 5 computer in network(computer A,B,C,D,E)
And computer A have to count ARP reply packet in the network. for example computer A can detect computer B send ARP reply packet to computer C 1/minute. 
Let's assume computer A is a analyzer host.

1. Computer B has an Ip : 192.168.1.2
2. Computer C has an Ip :192.168.1.3
3. Computer D has an Ip : 192.168.1.4
4. Computer E has an Ip : 192.168.1.5

And i use list in dictionary phyton the code is.

```
from scapy.all import *
reply=[]
reply.append({"src": " ", "dst" :" ","count": 0}]

def count_reply(paket): 
    for itung in reply:
        if itung['src']==paket['src'] and itung['dst']==paket['dst']:
            itung['count']+=1
            break       
        elif itung['src'] != paket['src'] and itung['dst'] != paket['dst']:
            reply.append(paket)
            paket['count']=1

def klasifikasi(pkt):
    # arp request
    if pkt[ARP].op == 2:
        returnpaket = {'src':pkt[ARP].psrc,'dst':pkt[ARP].pdst}
        return count_reply(returnpaket)

sniff(prn=klasifikasi, filter="arp", store=0)
print(reply)
```

And i tried to send arp reply flooding from computer C to Computer B. The ARP reply packet that sent is 7 packet. i expected the ouput is 
`reply=[{'count':0, 'src':" ", 'dst':" "}, {'count':7, 'src':192.168.1.3, 'dst':192.168.1.2}` But the actual output is

[image: The Actual Output]

I am following the code by using the solution that i asked yesterday here [How to remove duplicate item in List?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53979395/how-to-remove-duplicate-item-in-list)
How can i solve it? Please help me this is for my homework. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the multiple entries in your result is, that you already have an item in your reply list ({"src": " ", "dst" :" ","count": 0}), which causes your code to always trigger the "elif" part in your loop (function count_reply).

You should check every item in your reply list before making a decision on creating a new entry or updating an existing entry.

For example:

```
def count_reply(paket):
    if len(reply)==0:
        paket['count'] = 1
        reply.append(paket)
        found = True
    else:
        found = False
        for itung in reply:
            if itung['src']==paket['src'] and itung['dst']==paket['dst']:
                itung['count']+=1
                found = True
                break
    if not found:
        reply.append(paket)
        paket['count']=1
```